# What is the correct way to pass arguments by terminal in julia using argparse?

Tags: julia, argparse.jl

I want to pass arguments using argparse in julia, but I'm having problems.

```
using ArgParse
function parse_commandline(args)
s = ArgParseSettings()
@add_arg_table s begin
    "--hour"
        help = "value in hour"
        arg_type = Float64
        required = true
        #default = 0
    "--minute"
        help = "value in minute"
        arg_type = Float64
        required = true
        #default = 0
    "--second"
        help = "value in second"
        arg_type = Float64
        required = true
        #default = 0    
end
return parsed_args(args, s)
end

pa = parse_commandline()

function ConvRAToDeg(hour, minutes, second) 
    return (hour + minutes/60  + second/3600)*15
end

h = pa["hour"]
m = pa["minute"]
s = pa["second"]

RA = ConvRAToDeg(h, m, s)
println(RA)
```

I get the following error: 
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching parse_commandline()
Closest candidates are:
parse_commandline(!Matched::Any) at /home/usuario/practice_julia                                                                                                                                                                 ProperMotion.jl:6 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:265
in _start() at ./client.jl:321
while loading /home/usuario/practice_julia/ProperMotion.jl, in expression starting on line 27

Comment: You don't seem to pass argsuments to `pa = parse_commandline()` .

Comment: You need to replace `parse_commandline()` with `parse_commandline(ARGS)`.

Answer (score 1):

The next code works correctly.

```
function ConvRAToDeg(hour, minutes, second)
return (hour + minutes/60  + second/3600)*15
end

using ArgParse
function parse_commandline(args)
    s = ArgParseSettings()
    @add_arg_table s begin
        "--h"
            help = "value in hour"
            arg_type = Float64
            required = true
            #default = 0
        "--m"
            help = "value in minute"
            arg_type = Float64
            required = true
            #default = 0
        "--s"
            help = "value in second"
            arg_type = Float64
            required = true
            #default = 0    
    end
    pa = parse_args(args, s)
    h = pa["h"]
    m = pa["m"]
    s = pa["s"]
    RA = ConvRAToDeg(h, m, s)
    println(RA)
end
parse_commandline(ARGS)
```